# Apache (2.4) RequireAny with REQUEST_URI

Tags: apache, mod-auth-kerb

I've been trying to get this working and don't know where it's going wrong.

In the apache config I have the following section:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
  AuthType Kerberos
  AuthName "Login"
  KrbMethodNegotiate on
  KrbMethodK5Passwd on
  KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.LOCAL
  KrbServiceName HTTP/example.local@EXAMPLE.LOCAL
  Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/conf/http.keytab
  <RequireAny>
      Require valid-user
      Require local
      Require ip 192.168.2.190
      Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/my/InvalidCredentials#
      Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/my/PublicPage/*#
  </RequireAny>
</Directory>
```

The pages I'm trying to exclude from the authentication are like this:

- https://example.local/my/InvalidCredentials
- https://example.local/my/PublicPage/somevariabledata

All but the Require expr statements are working, the expressions must be wrong, but no idea what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should try with "If" instead before the RequireAny like this:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#(/my/InvalidCredentials$|/my/PublicPage/)#">
      Require all granted
</If>
<Else>
      <RequireAny>
      #all checks except the require expr
      </RequireAny>
</Else>
```

For me it looks simpler, more coherent and for me it works this way.

About your check, I am not really sure why it doesn't work, all the examples in the docs enclose expr with quotes but not sure its just that, but hope this other option helps.

In any case here is the link for Require expr examples for quicker reference:
[Require expr](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#reqexpr)